# Regex how to find pattern?

Tags: regex

I need to separate text below with Regex syntax. Actually I found recipes for `dddd-dddd` and `dddd-ddd[x]`. What with text? I need to get string with this value like this: `"British Journal of Applied Science & Technology"`. How to write it in regex?

```
337 British Journal of Applied Science & Technology 2231-0843 5
338 British Journal of Economics, Management & Trade 2278-098X 5
339 British Journal of Education, Society & Behavioural Science 2278-0998 6
340 British Journal of Environment and Climate Change 2231-4784 5
341 British Journal of Mathematics & Computer Science 2231-0851 4
342 British Journal of Medicine and Medical Research 2231-0614 8
343 British Journal of Pharmaceutical Research 2231-2919 4
344 British Microbiology Research Journal 2231-0886 9
345 Bromatologia i Chemia Toksykologiczna 0365-9445 5
346 Budownictwo Górnicze i Tunelowe 1234-5342 5
347 Budownictwo i Architektura 1899-0665 3
348 Budownictwo, Technologie, Architektura 1644-745X 3
349 Builder 1896-0642 2
350 Built Environment 0263-7960 10
351 Bulgarian Journal of Veterinary Medicine 1311-1477 8
352 Bulgarian Medicine 1314-3387 2
353 Bulletin de la Société des sciences et des lettres de Łódź, Série: Recherches sur les déformations 0459-6854 7
354 Bulletin of Alfred Nobel University. Series "Legal Science" 2226-2873 6
355 Bulletin of Geography. Socio-economic Series 1732-4254 10
356 Bulletin of Geography: Physical Geography Series 2080-7686 9
357 Bulletin of the Polish Academy of Sciences. Mathematics 0239-7269 9
358 Business and Economic Horizons 1804-1205 8
359 Business and Economics Research Journal 1309-2448 10
360 Business Process Management Journal 1463-7154 10
```

Comment: What program are you running your regex through?

Comment: Please be more clear about what you want to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=\d\s)\D+(?=\s\d)
```

That should find what you need. If you are interested in how it works:
The first part of the Regex (`(?<=\d\s)`) declares that the searched phrase must come after a digit (`\d`) followd by a whitespace (`\s`).

The second part (`\D+`) is what is actually found. It means any number of non digit characters.

The third part (`(?=\s\d)`) makes sure that the result is followed by another whitespace and digit.

Comment: This expression will not work magazine names that include digits, such as `"Perfect 10"`, `"J-14"`, `"Route 66 Magazine"` and of course `"2600: The Hacker Quarterly"`

Comment: `(?<=\d\s).+(?=\s[\dX]{4}-[\dX]{4})` if that is a Problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an expression that uses lookahead and lookbehind, like this:

```
(?<=\d{3}\s).*(?=\s\d{4}-)
```

This expression requires three digits followed by space in front of the text, and four digits preceded by space and followed by a dash after the text. The name itself is matched by a straight `.*` pattern.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/kQ6fC9/5)

Comment: I see no reason why the numbers couldn't go above 999, or, more importantly, under 100, and the "Legal Science" example probably ruins the lookahead too. Some minor fixes will make this work though.

Comment: @AndrisLeduskrasts "Legal Science" works like a charm (see the demo). As far as using more digits in the lookbehind goes, it should be a trivial fix for the OP to manage.

Comment: Oh okay he wanted that title, sorry then. As for the number, a beginner regex user may find it not so trivial as lookbehinds are fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify a target language or anything like that, here's how you could do it with perl:

```
cat test.txt | perl -pe 's/^\d+\s//' | perl -pe 's/[0-9X "-]+$//'
```

The second expression might need adaptation depending on how the rest of your data looks like.

This prints:

```
British Journal of Applied Science & Technology
British Journal of Economics, Management & Trade
British Journal of Education, Society & Behavioural Science
British Journal of Environment and Climate Change
[snip]
Bulletin of the Polish Academy of Sciences. Mathematics
Business and Economic Horizons
Business and Economics Research Journal
Business Process Management Journal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+ (.+) ....-.... \d+
```

Extracting:

```
British Journal of Applied Science & Technology
British Journal of Economics, Management & Trade
British Journal of Education, Society & Behavioural Science
British Journal of Environment and Climate Change
British Journal of Mathematics & Computer Science
British Journal of Medicine and Medical Research
British Journal of Pharmaceutical Research
[... cut ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{3})\s([\D]+)(\d{4}-\d{3,4}X?\s\d{1,2})
```

This splits the string into 3 capture groups:

> 1. 3 digits
> 2. Anything NOT containing a digit, up to the next digit
> 3. The reference at the end (assumes it begins with 4 digits and is in a consistent format)

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iS7qA2/1)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking for REGEX, but if you wanted something slightly more straight forward it looks like your document can easily be parsed using simple string manipulation. I offer this idea as an alternative for people not looking to use REGEX.

```
String tmp = "340 British Journal of Environment and Climate Change 2231-4784 5";
String ending = tmp.substring(tmp.length() - 11);
tmp = tmp.substring(0, (tmp.length() - 11)); //parse off the ending
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(tmp, " ");
String index = st.nextToken(); //reads the first int up to the first space.
tmp = tmp.substring(index.length()); //parse front
```

Now **tmp** is the name of the journal, **index** is the first few characters, and the reference at the end is saved as **ending**. This method only works presuming all the strings are exactly as listed above, or within similar bounds.

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
(?<=\d\s)\D+(?=\s\d)
```

works very well, but i found in my pdf that titles could have numbers, for example

```
338 British Journal of 5Economics, Management & Trade 2278-098X 5
```

How to properly parse it ? 
PS I write my app in C#(.NET).